# How to set height of neighbor div in scrollable div to same height

Tags: css, height

In a `div` with `overflow-y:auto` containing two neighbor `div` elements i need to set one of the two `div` elements to the same height as the other.

Simplified the html looks like the example below, where the `div` with class `content` is dynamically generated and the other `div` with class `backdrop` should get the same height as the element with class `content`.

```
<div class="container"
  <div class="backdrop"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Instead the `div` with class `backdrop` gets the height of outer div. So when the element with class `content` overflows the backdrop will get a smaller height then the div with class `content`.

Here an example to demonstrate the issue. Can this be fixed CSS-only or do i need to use jQuery to resize the height of one `div` to match the other?

```css
.container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
}

.backdrop {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 100, 0, 0.2);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

p {
  color: #FFF;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
    top:100px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: xx-large;
    text-align: center;
}

.content {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 60px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
  grid-column-gap: 2px;
}

.cell {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="backdrop"><p>
    Wait
    </p></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
            <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
            <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use grid, you might use it once more at the top level and set both elements inside the same cell, let backdrop inherit the height and set it in sticky position at top left;

Demo of the idea:

```css
.container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  display:grid;/* new */
}

.backdrop {
  z-index: 1;/*modified*/
  position: sticky;/*modified*/
  height: inherit;/*modified*/
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 100, 0, 0.2);
  grid-row:1;grid-column:1;/* new */
}

p {
  color: #FFF;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
    top:100px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: xx-large;
    text-align: center;
}

.content {
  grid-row:1;grid-column:1;/*new*/
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 60px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
  grid-column-gap: 2px;
}

.cell {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="backdrop"><p>
    Wait
    </p></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
            <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
            <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```